# Display commas after every output not after last

Tags: php, function, smarty

I have this function code:

```
 public function getMovieCategoryDetails($movieid){
        $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
        $tags = array();
         if ( !( $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM movie_tags_join WHERE movie_id=$movieid)") ) ) 
{
            exit( mysql_error( ) );
        }
while ( 0 < mysql_num_rows( $e ) && ( $s = mysql_fetch_array( $e ) ) )
        {
            extract( $s );
            $tags[$id] = array( );
            $tags[$id]['tag'] = $tag;

        }
        return $tags;
    }
```

And output code is:

```
{foreach from=$tags key=id item=val name=tags}
{$val.tag}
{/foreach}
```

Now is show: category1 category2 category3

I want: category1,category2,category3

Comment: Why not just `implode()` the array before assigning it into smarty?

Comment: I don't know how to use implode

Comment: @Michael: The view logic should be responsible for how it's displayed, not the model logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the top of my head I would suggest using smarty variables.

```
{foreach from=$tags key=id item=val name=tags}
    {if !$smarty.foreach.tags.first},{/if}{$val.tag}
{/foreach}
```

See [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.foreach.tpl) for further reference.